# Differences in "surprise" translations: 驚奇, 吃驚, 驚喜

Tags: grammar, mandarin, cantonese

This page lists multiple entries for `surprise`:

https://www.yellowbridge.com/chinese/dictionary.php

1) What's the difference among 驚奇, 吃驚, and 驚喜?

2) Are the meaning and uses the same for Cantonese?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 驚奇 (v) - be amazed; be surprised.
>
> Example: 對此事**驚奇**不已 (extremely **amazed** by this event)
>
> 驚奇 (adj) - amazing; surprising.
>
> Example:有**驚奇**效果 (having **amazing**/**surprising** effect)

~

> 吃驚 (v) - frighteningly surprised; frightened; suffer/get a scare
>
> Example: 一吃驚, 拔腿就跑 (once frightened, it ran)

~

> 驚喜 (n) - pleasant surprise
>
> Example: 一個驚喜 (a pleasant surprise)

These terms are used in both Mandarin and Cantonese

> *"to surprise (v)" in Chinese is " 讓/使/令(某人)驚訝"*

Comment: The last one you used 驚訝? Does it carry the same meaning and connotation as 驚喜? Thanks again!

Comment: 訝  in 驚訝 originally meant 'meet' ; 驚訝 ( meet+ surprise/ scare) =  'astonished',  which is a verb; or adjective 'astonishing ' ;  驚喜( pleasant surprise) is a noun

Comment: 驚 surprise 喜 delight; 驚喜 (surprising delight) =  'pleasant surprise' (n)